# Que flag eu poderia usar para parar a execução da função ler_disciplinas?

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct materias {

char disciplinas[20];
char semana[7][15];

}materias;

void ler_disciplinas ();

int main(){
materias m[100];

FILE* f;
f = fopen("/home/lucas/Área de Trabalho/prova2.txt","r");
ler_disciplinas(m,f);
fclose(f);

}
void ler_disciplinas (materias* m, FILE* f){

int i = 0,k = 0,j = 0;

for(;;){

    for(i = 0;;i++){
        (*m).disciplinas[i] = fgetc(f);
        if((*m).disciplinas[i] == ' '){break;}
    }
    printf("%s",(*m).disciplinas);

    for(j = 0;j<7;j++){
        for(k = 0;k<100;k++){
            (*m).semana[j][k] = fgetc(f);
            if((*m).semana[j][k] == ' ' || (*m).semana[j][k] == '\n'){break;}
        }
        printf("%s",(*m).semana[j]);
        if((*m).semana[j][k] == '\n'){break;}
    }   
}
}
```

---

É isso que o programa deveria ler:
matematica segunda quarta sexta'\n'
portugues terca quinta'\n'
biologia segunda quarta'\n'
geografia terca sexta

Comment: Não existe _flag_ para parar a execução. Existe o comando `break`. Acho importante dizer que no Stack Overflow, deve sempre fornecer o conteúdo do arquivo texto completo bem como enunciado do problema. Além disso, há vários problemas em seu código (não desista!). Você está tentando solucionar mas [fez a pergunta para o que acha que é o problema e não para o problema em si](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1202/839). Pergunte (quase) sempre sobre a mensagem de erro do código - que é Falha de Segmentação no caso - com o código e tudo relevante para rodar o programa (no caso, colocar o TXT).

Answer (score 0):

Bom, eu resolvi arrumar seu programa de modo a deixá-lo executável como referência. Você teve bastante tempo para tentar solucionar e talvez já tenha conseguido. De qualquer modo, tentei manter o seu padrão de raciocínio com algumas melhorias e modificações para que entenda o máximo possível dele.

O importante desse código é que ele vai servir de referência para você aprender a usar melhor os laços `while`, `do-while` e `for` que causaram grande parte de sua dor de cabeça - em evidência, o `for`. Utilizei os três realmente para fazê-lo aprender.

Procure mais sobre [laços de repetição](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pftIJjsk30&list=PL8iN9FQ7_jt5do6unj6ChD7T14hpcMgsk) em C. Procure também sobre [ponteiros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJzd9x2S2yg&list=PL8iN9FQ7_jt5_eMA_mn_4bdQMLjcnyeFs), [cadeias (*arrays*) de ponteiros e ponteiros de cadeias (*arrays*)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGB40IQkV28). São assuntos de suma importância, muito mais se considerar que são usados neste programa.

Eu sinceramente recomendo que tente fazer mais uma vez, que procure a teoria e tente novamente e assim sucessivamente. Só então, caso seja necessário, baseie-se no código aqui exposto.

Como de praxe, coloco minha versão desse programa. Novamente, recomendo que olhe somente depois de fazer o seu. Está também no [GitHub](https://github.com/jfcandidofilho/stackoverflow/blob/master/354602/programa.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARQUIVO "/home/lucas/Área de Trabalho/prova2.txt"

#define EOL '\n'


typedef struct _materia { /* Evite ambos 'typedef' e struct compartilhar nome */

    char nome[20];          /* 'nome' é melhor - referencia a matéria */
    char dia_semana[7][15]; /* 'dia_semana' é melhor (auto-explicativo) */

} materias;


void ler_disciplinas ();


int main(){

    materias m[100];
    FILE *f;

    printf("\n");

    f = fopen( ARQUIVO, "r" );

    fseek( f, 0L, SEEK_END ); 

    if( ftell( f ) > 0 ){ /* Só chama 'ler_disciplinas()' se 'f' não é vazio */

        rewind( f );

        ler_disciplinas( m, f );

    }

    fclose( f );

    printf("\n");

    /* Sempre retorne algum valor se sua main tem algum tipo (i.e. 'int') */
    return 0;

}


void ler_disciplinas( materias *m, FILE *f ){

    /* Nesta função:
    * 
    * - não faça o laço 'for' sem argumentos pois é uma péssima prática;
    * - há uma série de problemas quanto ao uso dos índices i, j, k;
    * - há uma série de problemas quanto ao uso de laços;
    * - há uma série de problemas quanto ao uso de ponteiros;
    * 
    * ! Atente-se ao funcionamento de laços e ponteiros. Reescrevi quase tudo.
    * 
    */

    int i, k, j;
    char temp;

    for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){

        j = -1;

        do { /* Obtém nome da materia */

            ++j;

            temp = fgetc( f );

            if( temp == ' ' || temp == EOL ) { /* EOL == Fim de linha */

                m[i].nome[j] = '\0'; /* Fecha a string */

                printf( "\t%s", m[i].nome );

                j = -1;     /* Sai do laço DO (j) */

            } else if( temp == EOF ){  /* EOF == Fim de arquivo */

                j = -1;     /* Sai do laço DO (j) */
                i = 100;    /* Sai do laço FOR (i) */

            } else {

                m[i].nome[j] = temp;

            }

        } while( j != -1 );


        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){ /* Índice do dia da semana */

            k = 0;

            while (k != -1 ){ /* Obtém o nome do dia da semana */

                temp = fgetc( f );

                if( temp == ' ' ) {

                    m[i].dia_semana[j][k] = '\0'; /* Fecha a string */

                    printf( " %s", m[i].dia_semana[j] );

                    k = -1;     /* Sai do laço WHILE (k) */

                } else if( temp == EOL ) { /* EOL == Fim de linha */

                    m[i].dia_semana[j][k] = '\0'; /* Fecha a string */

                    printf( " %s\n", m[i].dia_semana[j] );

                    k = -1;     /* Sai do laço WHILE (k) */
                    j = 7;      /* Sai do laço FOR (j) */

                } else if( temp == EOF ){ /* EOF == Fim de arquivo */

                    k = -1;     /* Sai do laço WHILE (k) */
                    j = 7;      /* Sai do laço FOR (j) */
                    i = 100;    /* Sai do laço FOR (i) */

                } else {

                    m[i].dia_semana[j][k] = temp;

                    k++;

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```